# Type Name not allowed/unexpected

Tags: c++

I am getting an error I do not understand, mind you i'm new to coding so this may be a simple error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
//Initialise Fahrenheit
float Fahrenheit = 95.0f;

//Initialise Celcius
double Celcius = float (Fahrenheit - 32)*0.5556;

cout << float Fahrenheit << "F is equal to" << double Celcius << "C" << endl;

cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Very simply, I am trying to write a program which outputs a value of Celsius for a value of Fahrenheit and i'm getting the following errors on line 14

```
cout << float Fahrenheit << "F is equal to" << double Celcius << "C" << endl;
```

- type name is not allowed
- expected a ;
- type double unexpected

These errors don't make sense to me in context with that line of code, perhaps I have made an error somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write

```
cout << Fahrenheit << " F is equal to " << Celcius << " C" << endl;
```

You can't add type names when using variables. Once you define a variable you just use it by its name.

Btw, casting `float` to `float` is superflous. And I fail to see the need to mix `double`s and `float`s. Just use `double` over `float` unless you have benchmarks to prove you need the smaller type.